# Angular 2 cannot work on IOS mobile Safari TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '(e=Object).assign.apply')

Tags: ios, angular, mobile-safari

My app works fine on mac Safari and mobile Chrome. But when setup on IOS mobile Safari I got an error and it stuck on 'Loading...' 
The error is in vendor.f16ec93a8ef3079cdc49.bundle.js:19787:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '(e=Object).assign.apply')
```

[vendor.f16ec93a8ef3079cdc49.bundle.js:19787 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV1Fl.png)

[Error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xldfL.png)

Did I miss some setting on Angular? Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please include a part of the code which produces this crash.

Comment: @the4kman Thanks for your reply. I added two pictures show the code.

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: Have exactly the same problem.